# Online ClickOnce Deployment Application and place an icon on the desktop/start menu

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I'm working on a online only winform application which I deploy using ClickOnce feature it uploads through FTP to the server and the user executes it online through http.

As you may already know, the Online only feature doesn't place any icons on the desktop, so everytime it runs the user got to run the setup.exe file to do it.

My question is, if there is anyway I could actually create an icon that may point to the setup file or any workaround to make sure the user got an accesible and easy way to run the app without having to look for the setup file everytime?

Users may not know a lot about computers so it can be a hard task to navigate all the way to the downloaded file everytime, and I want to make it easier for them.

I know that if I do an offline/online app it will solve the problem, but I would like it to be online only.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create desktop shortcut manually on the first app run, and point it to either to your app's url, or path to downloaded file (I guess, url will be safer in case user deletes the file). Code can look something like this (need adjusting to your URL):

```
void CheckForShortcut()
{
    ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

    if (ad.IsFirstRun)
    {
        Assembly code = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        string company = string.Empty;
        string description = string.Empty;

        if (Attribute.IsDefined(code, typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute)))
        {
            AssemblyCompanyAttribute ascompany = (AssemblyCompanyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(code,
                typeof(AssemblyCompanyAttribute));
            company = ascompany.Company;
        }

        if (Attribute.IsDefined(code, typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)))
        {
            AssemblyDescriptionAttribute asdescription = (AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(code,
                typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute));
            description = asdescription.Description;
        }

        if (company != string.Empty && description != string.Empty)
        {
            string desktopPath = string.Empty;
            desktopPath = string.Concat(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
                "\\", description, ".appref-ms");

            string shortcutName = string.Empty;
            shortcutName = string.Concat(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs),
                "\\", company, "\\", description, ".appref-ms");

            System.IO.File.Copy(shortcutName, desktopPath, true);
        }

    }
}
```

credits to http://geekswithblogs.net/murraybgordon/archive/2006/10/04/93203.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What is your reason for wanting an online only ClickOnce app? I always recommend offline unless your app is really an edge case.

There's very little difference between online and offline. All the same files are downloaded to the same location on the client. Offline apps add an entry to the 'Add/Remove Programs', a start menu shortcut, and an optional desktop shortcut (if you are targeting .NET 3.5+). The ability to uninstall through Add/Remove Programs is key. It makes supporting your application *much* easier when users have install problems.

Also, you mention users running the setup.exe every time. This is unnecessary. The setup.exe will contain your bootstrapped pre-requisites and then launch the app when it finishes. If the user has run the setup.exe once, they only need to click the link to the .application file. That will definitely speed up the app's start time. Also, in many cases the user has to have admin privileges to run the setup.exe; clicking the .application doesn't (assuming someone with admin privileges has already run the setup.exe).

In conclusion, there really isn't an answer here :). But...

1. Make absolutely sure your reasoning is sound for not doing an offline install instead.
2. After running the setup.exe once, direct users to click on the .application url (or the desktop shortcut if you switch to offline) instead of the setup.exe.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no reliable way for running online only ClickOnce application than creating shortcut to that setup.exe.